# The presented password is invalid - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a login form which will take the user from the database. I read a couple of tutorials, but I couldn't understand the securing quite well. I followed [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) and the only differences I made are that I removed salt and isActive from the User class. I just copied the rest and then created the tables in the database and added a user and a group - name: admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN and listed their id-s in the user_group table. But whatever I try, I get the same mistake - The presented password is invalid. Could you help me to fix this, please? And maybe some tutorial will be a help although I read about 4-5 and I'm still not getting everything.

Here is my config file:

```
security:
   encoders:
      EM\MyFriendsBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm:        sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations:       1

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

providers:
    administrators:
        entity: { class: EMMyFriendsBundle:User }

firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path:  /login
            check_path:  /login_check

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: Why did you remove the salt property? It is important for password generation. I would add it and see if it works

Comment: At first it stayed there, but it didn't worked, too. I removed it because I don't understand it very well. I know that it is a random string added to the password for extra security, but nothing more.

Comment: How did you add the password to the database? You need to store an encoded password, not a plain-text password

Comment: Maybe here is the problem - I add it directly from PHPMyAdmin and my table row is: id: 1, username: admin, password: 123, salt:123

Comment: That is the reason it is not working. You need to store an encoded password.

Comment: Or maybe not, because now I tried to encode it with this encoder http://scriptserver.mainframe8.com/sha1.php  and it still doesn't work.

Comment: 40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef - this is the encoded version for 123 and it doesn't work, I also tried to add the salt 123 and encode 123123 and add it like a password, but still nothing.

Comment: Try to encode it using the Symfony encoder. Not sure it will provide the same results as the encoder you are using

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but how to encode it with the Symfony encoder :( Something like this?  $password = $encoder->encodePassword('adminpass', $user->getSalt());
        $user->setPassword($password);

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#book-security-encoding-user-password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the password before saving it to the database. Please see:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#book-security-encoding-user-password